# Dependency Injection in MAUI (Android and iOS)

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, maui

I am trying to use same code from Xamarin in .NET MAUI. In my Xamarin Forms project I had this code:

```cs
private static readonly string serial = Serial();

private static string Serial()
{
    string getnewSerial = DependencyService.Get<iSerial>().GetSerial();
    return getnewSerial;
}
```

and I have this interface:

```cs
{
    public interface iSerial
    {
         string GetSerial();
    }
}
```

and on Android:

```cs
class Serial : iSerial
{
    public string GetSerial()
    {
        string getserial = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
        return getserial;
    }
}
```

and iOS:

```cs
public class Serial : iSerial
{
    public string GetSerial()
    {
        string getserial = Convert.ToString(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor);
        return getserial;
    }
}
```

but with .NET MAUI it doesn't work.

I have registered it in MauiProgram.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISerial, Serial>();
```

but when I try to use it like this:

```cs
private static readonly string serial = Serial();

private static string Serial()
{
    string getnewSerial = DependencyService.Get<iSerial>().GetSerial();
    return getnewSerial;
}
```

I get an error. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you used the dependency service in the xamarin.form to call the platform natvie code. But in the maui, the dependency service can be replaced by the Conditional compilation or Partial classes.

1. Use the Conditional compilation: Put the following code in the share project:

```
    string getserial;
#if Android
    getserial = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
#elif IOS
    getserial = Convert.ToString(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor);
#endif
```

And for the way about using Partial class, you can refer to the [official document about Invoking platform code in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0)

Answer (score -1):

If your interface name is **`ISerial`** then you should use the same name while consuming it.

There is also a typo error while you are using the resolver.

It should be

```
string getnewSerial = DependencyService.Get<**I**Serial>().GetSerial();
```

instead of

```
string getnewSerial = DependencyService.Get<**i**Serial>().GetSerial();
```

Comment: DependencyService does not exist in .NET MAUI

Comment: It is exist as per this microsoft link - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.dependencyservice?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: Dependency service was meant for Xamarin Platform calls and its not the recommended way to do things in MAUI, if it exists its for compatibility reasons and will be removed as soon as they stop supporting compatibility with XF migrations, do you really want to write 'n' number of platform services that will need to be changed when this drops? Why not recommend someone who is writing new code to follow the best possible approach?

Comment: If a typo were the problem, there would be a compiler error, but I'm certain that the OP is dealing with a runtime error.